# Error about making Table View from String and model

Tags: swift, uikit

in swift UIKit

Error about making Table View from String and model

Could not cast value of type 'CloudApp.addCatogrey' (0x104948470) to 'Swift.String' (0x1052195b8).

An error occurs when I press send
I want to display the data for one of the sections through the model (addCatogrey)

view control file

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: arry data

    let sectionMenu = ["all", "Fav", "Delete"]
    var arrS1 : [addCatogrey] = []
    var arrS2 = ["favorite"]
    var arrS3 = ["delete other"]
    
    var sectionData : [Int: [Any]] = [:]
    
    //MARK: Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var addNewCatogery: UIBarButtonItem!
    

    @IBOutlet var tableCatogery: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sectionData = [0 : arrS1 , 1 : arrS2, 2 : arrS3]
        
        self.arrS1 = helperCora().getCatog()
    }

    

    @IBAction func addMenuNew(_ sender: Any) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Create an album", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)
        alert.textFields![0].placeholder = "name album"
        alert.textFields![0].textAlignment = .right
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "save", style: .default, handler: { ـ in
            if let textFileds = alert.textFields {
                let links = textFileds[0].text

                self.arrS1.append(addCatogrey(nameCatog: links!))
                helperCora().storeCatog(name: addCatogrey(nameCatog: links!))
                                
                self.sectionData = [0 : self.arrS1 , 1 : self.arrS2, 2 : self.arrS3]
                self.tableCatogery.reloadData()
            }
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    
    
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionData.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (sectionData[section]?.count)!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionMenu[section]
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellMenu

        cell.textMenu.text = sectionData[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row] as! String
        return cell
    }


}
```

model file

```
struct addCatogrey {

    var nameCatog : String
}
```

Coradata file [SAVE and GET]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class helperCora : ViewController {
    

    //MARK: Data For Menu --------- 1
    func storeCatog (name : addCatogrey) {
        
        guard let AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}
        let mangeContext = AppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        guard let myEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: mangeContext) else { return }
        let nameCat = NSManagedObject.init(entity: myEntity, insertInto: mangeContext)
        nameCat.setValue(name.nameCatog, forKey: "nameCat")
        
        do {
            try mangeContext.save()
            print("========== Secsess =========")
        }catch {
            print("========== Error =========")
        }
    }
    //MARK: Data For Menu --------- 2
    func getCatog () -> [addCatogrey] {

        var catog : [addCatogrey] = []

        guard let AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return []}
        let context = AppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")

        do {
            let reselt = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]

            for mangeCatoj in reselt {
                let title = mangeCatoj.value(forKey: "nameCat") as! String
                let Catogery = addCatogrey(nameCatog: title)
                catog.append(Catogery)

            }
            print("====== secsecc ========")
        }catch {

            print("====== error ========")
        }
        return catog
    }
 
}
```

Comment: You say, `sectionData[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row] as! String` but `sectionData[0]` is not an array of strings.

Comment: I can't make the model with the string

Comment: convert addCatogrey model array to string array.

Comment: or convert arr2 and arr3 to addCatogrey model array and add into sectionData array